# Como separar valores de uma resposta json e somar seus resultados?

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Tenho a seguinte resposta do AJAX:

```
[{"valor":"100","dt_month":"11"},
 {"valor":"150","dt_month":"11"},
 {"valor":"1324.50","dt_month":"9"},
 {"valor":"12.35","dt_month":"5"}]`
```

Gostaria de separar em dois arrays, sendo que o `valor` soma de acordo com o `dt_month`.

Resultado esperado:

```
arr1=[11, 9, 5];
arr2=[250, 1324.50, 12.35];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não seria melhor criar um objeto com as chaves de cada mês? Algo da seguinte forma:

```
let json = [{"valor":"100","dt_month":"11"},
            {"valor":"150","dt_month":"11"},
            {"valor":"1324.50","dt_month":"9"},
            {"valor":"12.35","dt_month":"5"}]

let result = {};
for(var i of json){
    if(!(i["dt_month"] in result)){
        result[i["dt_month"]] = 0;
    }
    result[i["dt_month"]] += parseFloat(i["valor"]);
}
```

Nesse caso, para acessar os valores basta colocar `result["<valor_do_mês>"]`.

Se você quiser realmente fazer com dois vetores, deveria ficar da seguinte forma:

```
let json = [{"valor":"100","dt_month":"11"},
        {"valor":"150","dt_month":"11"},
        {"valor":"1324.50","dt_month":"9"},
        {"valor":"12.35","dt_month":"5"}]

let dates = [];
let sums = [];
for(var i of json){
     if(dates.indexOf(i["dt_month"]) < 0){
        dates.push(i["dt_month"]);
        sums.push(0);
    }
    sums[dates.indexOf(i["dt_month"])] += parseFloat(i["valor"]);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Consegui o resultado que queria. Obs: para os valores não inteiros só mudei parseInt para parseFloat.